# Accessing collection field inside python dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```py
totalHotelsInTown=hotels.aggregate([ {"$group": {"_id": "$Town", "TotalRestaurantInTown": {"$sum":1}} } ])

NumOfHotelsInTown={}

for item in totalHotelsInTown:
    NumOfHotelsInTown[item['_id']]=item['TotalRestaurantInTown']

results = hotels.aggregate(
        [{"$match": {"cuisine": cuisine}},
         {"$group": {"_id": "$town", "HotelsCount": {"$sum": 1} }}, {"$project": {"HotelsCount":1,"Percent": {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$HotelsCount", NumOfHotelsInTown["$_id"]]}, 100]}}},  {"$sort": {"Percent": 1}},
{"$limit": 1}])
```

I want to pass the value of `"_id"` field as a key to python dictionary, but the interpreter is taking `"$_id"` itself as a key instead of its value and giving a `KeyError` because of that. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

'NumOfHotelsInTown' dictionary has key value pairs of place and number of hotels

When I am trying to retrieve the value from NumOfHotelsInTown dictionary,
I am giving the key dynamically with "$_id".

The exact error I am getting is:

```
 {"$group": {"_id": "$borough", "HotelsCount": {"$sum": 1} }}, {"$project": {"HotelsCount":1,"Percent": {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$HotelsCount", NumOfHotlesInTown["$_id"]]}, 100]}}},  {"$sort": {"Percent": 1}},
KeyError: '$_id'
```

Comment: Can you post the python code which is accessing the `$_id` field, and the exact error you see?

Comment: @RobertSeaman, yeah sure!

Comment: @RobertSeaman, have edited the post with more detailed code and the error I am getting because of the issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the exact error you see? It would probably be worth printing the value of `item` or `results` or of whichever variable it's throwing your exception on.

Comment: @RobertSeaman, hi! added the result after the group stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do, but you can't dynamically run python code during a MongbDB `aggregate`.

What you should do instead:

1. Get the total counts for every borough (which you have already done)
2. Get the total counts for every borough for a given cuisine (which you have part of)
3. Use python to compare the 2 totals to produce a list of percentages and not MongoDB

For example:

```
group_by_borough = {"$group": {"_id": "$borough", "TotalRestaurantInBorough": {"$sum":1}} }
count_of_restaurants_by_borough = my_collection.aggregate([group_by_borough])
restaurant_count_by_borough = {doc["_id"]: doc["TotalRestaurantInBorough"] for doc in count_of_restaurants_by_borough}

count_of_cuisines_by_borough = my_collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"cuisine": cuisine}}, group_by_borough])
cuisine_count_by_borough = {doc["_id"]: doc["TotalRestaurantInBorough"] for doc in count_of_cuisines_by_borough}

percentages = {}

for borough, count in restaurant_count_by_borough.items():
    percentages[borough] = cuisine_count_by_borough.get(borough, 0) / float(count) * 100

# And if you wanted it sorted you can use an OrderedDict

from collections import OrderedDict
percentages = OrderedDict(sorted(percentages.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```